# The difference between build and publish in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am a little confused about the difference between build and publish in the visual studio.

What is the difference between building a program and publishing a program?

Comment: See: [Deploying Applications, Services, and Components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtzawcsz.aspx)

Comment: @Habib That link does not mention building an application, just publishing.

Comment: @KyleDelaney Along with many thousands of other pages providing an answer to the question, many of which are going to provide much more and better information on the subject.  Adding one more isn't useful.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a link to the best one, then.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Build compiles the source code into a (hopefully) runnable application. Publish takes the results of the build, along with any needed third-party libraries and puts it somewhere for other people to run it. It may also make some changes to make the app runnable in the destination, depending on the framework and type of app (e.g. a console app may just copy files, while a web app may set up the configs based on the destination).

Your confusion may come from the fact that Publish will also build the application if it thinks it needs to (e.g. if there are source code changes).

Comment: Does 'Publish' do anything more than copying files? Such as configuration files transformation?

Comment: Could I just build (compile) and copy manually the DLL files to my web server folder, would it be the same?

Comment: @Olegl answer is more up to date and clears the difference between .NET Core and .NET Framework

Answer (score 125):

There are some significant differences between Build and Publish targeting .NET Framework application vs .NET Core applications:

Building **.NET Framework** applications will generate the same files as Publish. It will create all the dependencies as binaries including external dependencies (NuGet packages, for instance). So the product of `dotnet build` *is* ready to be transferred to another machine to run.

Building **.NET Core** applications, if the project has third-party dependencies, such as libraries from NuGet, they're resolved from the NuGet cache and aren't available with the project's built output. Therefore the product of `dotnet build` *isn't* ready to be transferred to another machine to run. You need to run Publish to get all 3rd party dependencies as binaries in output folder.

**EDIT 10/21/22 --**
For Dotnet core projects before 3.0 this is the case after 3.0 third party dependencies are included in the output you can view that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#description).

The dotnet build command builds the project and its dependencies into a set of binaries. The binaries include the project's code in Intermediate Language (IL) files with a .dll extension. Depending on the project type and settings, other files may be included, such as:

*An executable that can be used to run the application, if the project type is an executable targeting .NET Core 3.0 or later.
Symbol files used for debugging with a .pdb extension.
A .deps.json file, which lists the dependencies of the application or library.
A .runtimeconfig.json file, which specifies the shared runtime and its version for an application.
Other libraries that the project depends on (via project references or NuGet package references).
For executable projects targeting versions earlier than .NET Core 3.0, library dependencies from NuGet are typically NOT copied to the output folder. They're resolved from the NuGet global packages folder at run time. With that in mind, the product of dotnet build isn't ready to be transferred to another machine to run. To create a version of the application that can be deployed, you need to publish it (for example, with the dotnet publish command). For more information, see .NET Application Deployment.
For executable projects targeting .NET Core 3.0 and later, library dependencies are copied to the output folder. This means that if there isn't any other publish-specific logic (such as Web projects have), the build output should be deployable.*

Comment: Thank you @Olegl, I came here looking for _this_ answer; Trying to understand the transition from the classic .NET Framework to .NET Core.

Comment: @nqramjets there are quite a lot of differences, sorry I cannot iterate all of those here. Depending on the complexity of the application transition can go very differently :) but if you have the opportunity to migrate, I would definitely do so

Comment: A potentially important observation I have made during testing with .NET Core is that when running and debugging a program in Visual Studio, the bin folder is used. Therefore you should allow local developer settings to be copied to the bin folder (if you have such files), but might want to exclude them from publication (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42503825/397817 for how).

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer, especially with dotnet framework part saying that Build and Publish generate same thing. With VS2019, for a aspdotnet application, Publish is for sure needed to iis deployment.

Answer (score 12):

Building and Publishing a project in VS are totally different things.

The *build* process involves *compiling* your project's code and storing the binary result into DLLs. You can find them under \bin\debug\ folder or \bin\release\ folder under your project's root. That depends if you're building in Debug or Release mode. These DLLs store the application's binary data and can be referenced into other projects.

The *publishing* process always comes after the build process. Let's suppose that you have a ASP.NET application. If you want to use your project, building your web application into DLLs will not be sufficient, since you need to host your web application into a web server which will be IIS or ASP.NET development server. It involves hosting your application to be accessed by client entities. Basically, you can publish web applications and web services.

Comment: @HamdiBaligh Yes, but you need to be sure to copy any dependencies not installed in the GAC on the server.

Comment: We always used to deploy to IIS by copying the `bin` folder, so is this now broken since _Publish_ was invented?

Comment: You're confusing publishing with deploying.