# Excluding File From Publish Directory in VS 2017 .NET Core Project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, dotnet-cli

I have a `.gitignore` file in the `wwwroot` folder of my project that I am trying to exclude from being published. The following code does not seem to work:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="wwwroot\.gitignore">
    <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

When I publish the project using the `dotnet publish` command, the `.gitignore` file is still found in the output directory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to use `Update` like so:

```
<Content Update="wwwroot\.gitignore">
  <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
</Content>
```

Comment: Is it just me or that didn't work, the files are still published

Comment: Oh wait, got mixed up with CopyToOutoutDirectory

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on what's the difference between the `Include` and `Update` attribute?

Comment: No idea but one works and the other does not. MSBuild is not well documented.

Comment: I think I found the answer. Everything inside the `wwwroot` folder is already included (which means that `CopyToPublishDirectory` is already defined). You have to, either `Remove` something and then re-`Include` it, or `Update` its metadata with some other option.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code

```
<Content Include="wwwroot\.gitignore"> with 
<None Include="wwwroot\.gitignore">
```

How did I get to know this? 
While  going through the code of .csproj file I came across this tag (None) that was put by visual studio in front of all publish profiles' file (.pubxml). so I tried with my files as well and it worked like a charm.

The MSDN article on the [build action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/0c6xyb66(v=vs.100).aspx) property explains the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the voted answer did not work for me. I had an ASP.NET Core web project and I was using Web Deploy to a remote server. I was trying to exclude a whole folder under wwwroot from being included in the deployment and after various trials and different combinations of things the only thing that worked for me was a combination of both:

1. Exclude the folder from the project (i.e. right-click > Exclude from project)

**AND**

2. Adding the following to my .csproj exactly as it is but changing `wwwroot\\profiles` to be the directory you want to exclude. You also have to repeat the whole snippet for each folder you want to exclude:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>wwwroot\\profiles</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </ItemGroup>
```