# Publishing Polymer + ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, polymer, visual-studio-2017

I am a great fan of ASP.NET Core and have followed its evolution from the first steps to the integration in VS2017 with the return to the msbuild-based project system. I am also a great fan of Google Polymer and now that the 2.0 release is almost done I want to experiment with the combination of both.

I created an ASP.NET Core Web Api project that is going to implement a REST API for the Polymer frontend. Then I pointed my command line to the wwwroot folder and did

```
polmyer init
```

to create an application template which creates some template html files and a bower_components directory with all the basic dependencies, all in the wwwroot folder!

My question is:

VS2017 has a publish function which by default publishes everything that's in the wwwroot folder but probably would allow me to exclude specific files or folders. On the other hand Polymer CLI as a build function that allows me to compile ES6 to ES5, minimize either HTML, CSS, JS or all and bundle the files. How can I combine the two to give me a single-click publish experience in VS2017?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my current solution:

With VS2017 create a new ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project. Add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles Nuget package to be able to serve static files.

Navigate to the *wwwroot* directory with a command line and do

```
polymer init
```

Follow the wizard to create your desired polymer project type.

Open the *csproj* file in the VS IDE and find the item group where the *wwwroot* directory is included as a folder. Comment out this line and add two new lines. The first one prevents VS from copying the entire *wwwroot* directory. The second one adds in again the polymer build directory so we can reference it later in a copy task.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!--<Folder Include="wwwroot\" />-->
  <Content Update="wwwroot\**\*" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />
  <ClientFiles Include="wwwroot\build\default\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

(Note that I used *Update* instead of *Include* in the content node!)

Create a batch file *polymer-build.cmd* with the following content and place it in the project root directory. This will make polymer build the client files before each VS publish

```
cd wwwroot
polymer build
```

Here you could add options like --js-compile, --css-minify etc.

Create a new target node in the *csproj* file to call the batch file before publishing

```
<Target Name="PolymerBuild" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="polymer-build.cmd" />
</Target>
```

Finally create another target node with a copy task to copy the polymer build directory to the wwwroot directory

```
<Target Name="PolymerPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ClientFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishUrl)\wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)" />
</Target>
```

**Addition**

you may also want to suppress TypeScript compilation which you can do in the *csproj* via

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
</PropertyGroup>
```

References:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/11/07/how-to-recursively-copy-files-using-the-copy-task/
- https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli
- [Excluding File From Publish Directory in VS 2017 .NET Core Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42490607/excluding-file-from-publish-directory-in-vs-2017-net-core-project)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `polymer init` command in the pre-build command of the project in Vusual Stddio.

Comment: Thanks but `polymer init` is a one time task during project setup. It would have to be `polymer build` (--options) and I don't want to execute it during every VS build! `polymer build` is more like VS publish so it would have to be executed on VS publish or directly before (if there is such an event). `polymer build` creates a build sub directory and that is the one that would have to be VS-published not all the other files in wwwroot. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @NicolasR How is the Polymer and ASP.NET Core working for you?  Do you have a blog or documentation anywhere.  I am thinking to do the same thing

Comment: @JordanMcDonald Sorry, no blog :-( So far I really like the combination. I like the clean separation: ASP.NET for a REST API, EF Core for abstracting from the concrete database technology and Polymer for a client side single page app with a standards conform component system. I also like that the server side can now run on many platforms, even on a RasPi with Linux. Polymer hides the differing support for web components by the major browsers. The ES6 class syntax for defining components in Polymer is a great help for someone coming from C++/C#. The Polymer community could be greater though.

Comment: @NicolasR I am looking forward to do the same thing, can u please post a kind of tutorial somewhere? or perhaps make a basic template? so others users like me can also benefit from it? thanks

Comment: @touseef ok, give me a little time, I will try to set it up on github.

Comment: @JordanMcDonald Try this: https://github.com/nicolasr75/PolymerAspNetCore

Comment: this is great help @NicolasR  thanks a lot, I look forward to contributing :)