# Deploying code changes to a asp.net website hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

There is a website hosted on IIS and we have done code changes which need to be deployed.

If only code behind changes have been done, then I think only the dll in the bin folder needs to be replaced. If only the aspx file is changed, then only that file needs to be replaced and not the dll. Is this correct? Also, should we build and replace the files or publish?

Comment: There's an easy way to find out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If only code behind changes have been done, then I think only the dll
>   in the bin folder needs to be replaced. If only the aspx file is
>   changed, then only that file needs to be replaced and not the dll. Is
>   this correct?

Yes this is correct.
In addition the update for *.cs, config etc files is the same for aspx.
(not recommended: but you can even modify them inside the server by notepad).

> Also, should we build and replace the files or publish?

Actually if you just copy the dll, it does not matter - you can just build.
see this question: [build vs publish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320618/6844481)

Comment: Do we need to change project config settings like dev or release mode?

Comment: @variable sorry it doesn't clear what you are asking, what do you mean by config setting?

Comment: When we build or publish a project, it can be set to either Debug or Release mode configuration setting. Thats what I was trying to say.

Comment: Oh, you are asking about Configuration Manager, it is better to make sure you are on Release (for optimization purposes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27320618/6844481)