# How to copy appsettings.json to DEBUG folder, as part of dotnet build

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, console-application, visual-studio-debugging, appsettings

I am having a console application, which is using *appsettings.json* for holding the configuration values.

In Visual Studio IDE , when I set AlwaysCopy for *appsettings.json*, it will be copied to the DEBUG folder, as part of BUILD.

But, in .net core, when I run `dotnet build`, it is not copying *appsettings.json* to DEBUG folder. 
I am already having below xml configuration added to .csproj

```
  <Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
```

When I do `dotnet publish`, it is getting copied to publish folder. But, it is not happening when I do `dotnet build`. Can you please tell, why it is not happening & what should I do to copy the appsettings.json to DEBUG folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in another thread is Stackoverflow([The difference between build and publish in VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320374/the-difference-between-build-and-publish-in-vs)). In .NET Core, build & publish are different, as compared to .NET Framework.

> Building .NET Framework applications will generate the same files as
>   Publish. It will create all the dependencies as binaries including
>   external dependencies(NuGets for instance). So the product of dotnet
>   build is ready to be transferred to another machine to run
>
> Building .NET Core applications, if the project has third-party
>   dependencies, such as libraries from NuGet, they're resolved from the
>   NuGet cache and aren't available with the project's built output.
>   Therefore the product of dotnet build isn't ready to be transferred to
>   another machine to run. You need to run Publish to get all 3rd party
>   dependencies as binaries in output folder.

If we want a file to be part of publish, we need to add below attribute. In build, this file is not copied to the DEBUG/RELEASE folder.

```
<Content Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
  </Content>
```

Comment: This is still only part of answer. How did you achieve (if at all you completed) to copy the appsettings.json file in Debug/Release mode?

Comment: @SivaSenthil, It has been sometime, since I worked on dotnet core. If I remember correctly, I used publish option to get the `appsettings.json`, to get it to publish folder, as I have mentioned in the questioni.