# What is the difference between dotnet build and dotnet publish commands?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am a little confused regarding ***dotnet build vs dotnet publish*** topic.
When I say difference, I mean what is the physical difference among them.
I see that dotnet build generates the same files as dotnet publish unless it is self-contained.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between build and publish in VS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27320374/the-difference-between-build-and-publish-in-vs)

Comment: I share your confusion. I have two different projects, both .NET 7, both console applications. One will only publish if using `dotnet build`, the other will only publish if using `dotnet publish`. I had to configure my build server differently to handle each case.

Answer (score 0):

`dotnet build` will generate **dll files** in folder **bin** in your local project folder

`dotnet publish` will build, generate dll files and **deploy** in where you want.

For example, you can deploy to *a hosting provider, to a file folder on your network (you can manually copy from there to a folder used by IIS), to IIS on your development computer as a testing environment, to a server on your company's internal network*.

Read more **"How to: Deploy a Web Project Using One-Click Publish in Visual Studio"**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465337(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN